# Why Laravel homestead doesn't show the welcome page from view and show another?

Tags: laravel, web, homestead

I've installed Laravel homestead following tutorials and documentation but Im not able to view the template page located in resources>views. Instead, the page shows another laravel page I dont know why.

Running on Windows 10, Visual Studio Code, git bash..

[My laravel 'welcome' page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLoS6.png)

Comment: this is the expected page for the newest laravel version (8).

Answer (score 0):

You're using Laravel version 8.x. With 8.x welcome page changed. So there is no problem. Start coding: )